# Chrome extension does not recognise getElementsByClassName("listBodyRow")[i] but running in chrome console works

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

It works in Console with an error but gives me the desired output on my DOM.

The below is the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined
    at :3:84

I've tried using Try...Catch to ignore the error, but maybe that's a bad idea as im just ignoring the error. And it also does not work.

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var activeTickets = document
        .getElementById("NewGadget0-listBody").getElementsByClassName("listBodyRow")[i].getElementsByClassName("listBodyCell")[12].innerHTML;

    console.log('%c%s', 'color: #00e600', activeTickets);


    if (activeTickets.includes("Priority 4")) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("listBodyRow")[i].style.backgroundColor = "#D2ECEF";
    }

    if (activeTickets.includes("Priority 3")) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("listBodyRow")[i].style.backgroundColor = "#9BC972";
    }

    if (activeTickets.includes("Priority 2")) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("listBodyRow")[i].style.backgroundColor = "#F7D180";
    }

    if (activeTickets.includes("Priority 1")) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("listBodyRow")[i].style.backgroundColor = "#F96B6B";
    }

}
```

It should run and highlight the background, which is does in console. But not my chrome extension.

Comment: Put your `<script>` tag in your `<head>` using an external `src`, and use a load Event to make sure the DOM is loaded.

Comment: is there really (at least) 100 elements with class `listBodyRow` in the element with id `NewGadget0-listBody` - each of which has at least 13 elements with class containing `listBodyCell` .. and why do you use `document
        .getElementById("NewGadget0-listBody").getElementsByClassName("listBodyRow")[i]` in one case and `document
        .getElementsByClassName("listBodyRow")[i]` in others? you know they could be different ... have you heard of `.querySelector` and `.querySelectorAll` ... these would make your code much simpler

Comment: Oh good point about document.getElementsByClassName("listBodyRow")[i], i will look into that.

Comment: Oh Bravo you genius! Such a silly mistake, it was due to there being only 90 elements so when it looped it errored out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To access/manipulate the webpage DOM you have two ways:**

1. **Either declare content script(s) in *manifest.json*** and use messaging:

   `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()` from your background/popup page to the injected content script's `chrome.runtime.onMessage` listener, which will perform actions on webpage and transfer results via `sendResponse` callback as per the documentation (note: only JSON-ifiable objects like numbers, strings, arrays, simple objects are supported, which means not DOM elements, not classes, not functions). In case the content script needs to initiate communication to an extension page it should use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`.
2. **Or use Tabs API to inject a content script**:
   `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, details, callback)`

   - Required permissions: `"tabs"`, `"https://www.example.com/*"`
     (or `"<all_urls>"` and variants like `"*://*/*"`, `"http://*/*"`, `"https://*/*"`)
   - A better choice, in case of explicit user activation, is to use `"activeTab"` permission instead of `"tabs"` and `"<all_urls>"` because it serves as an alternative for many uses of `"<all_urls>"`, but *displays no warning message during installation*.
   - `.executeScript()` may be used with a callback function that receives an array of last evaluated expressions in the injected content script, one element per each frame in which it's injected within the tab. Chrome uses `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` on the results internally, thus restricting the supported types to plain objects and simple stringifiable values like number/string, or arrays thereof.
     So it doesn't work for DOM elements, functions, custom properties, getters/setters: you'll need to manually map/extract the required data and pass it in a simple array/object.